# Antivirus for Thesis

Tags: antivirus

I just want to ask if you know any book or technical papers and theses regarding computer viruses and anti-viruses. 'cause we're having a hard time looking for updated books regarding anti-viruses/viruses. Right now, we're just basing our documentation on the book of Mark Ludwig, The Giant Black Book of Computer Viruses and other books that are pretty out-of-date already.

First hand advices from your experiences in the industry are also welcome.

It will be very helpful for our thesis which is an anti-virus as well. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

"The Art of Computer Virus Research and Defense" by Peter Szor is interesting, and also references a lot of other materials.

Answer (score 0):

Books will be out of date very quickly because the field changes so quickly. Because of that, the anti-virus software also changes rapidly.

Most of the recent work will be posted online. Nearly every Anti-Virus company posts blogs about recent research and new viruses found.

- [FortiGuard](http://www.fortiguard.com/threats.html)
- [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/weblog/)
- [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware.aspx)

You can also use Google [Scholar](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?as_ylo=2008&q=computer%20viruses&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) to search for papers and theses.

Comment: Thanks schroeder! I guess I'll be limiting our thesis to a simple virus detector and remover only. Because it is project-based so we won't have a lot of time if we make a fully functional antivirus. Well, Thanks again. :)